# PyCharm The apply interpreter button is greyed out

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]I'm using PyCharm for a game im making and in the settings section there is a section thats called 'interpreter' I wanted to update `pygame` from 1.9 to 2.0 because the version was too old, but I accidentally clicked on the `apply` button. Then the `venv` file became orange and then I tried something and something and it was grey again. Butt now the `apply` button is grey, what is even that button? I have OCD and if I cannot get it turn normal again I would have to create a new project, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could send a screenshot for more detail.

Comment: I just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apply button being gray means that you didn't change anything. If you changed something in the settings, you could click apply but since you already did there are no new changes to be made so it is in grey. You don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Yay! Thank you very much